# Kendo UI grid is not showing data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using MVC Kendo grid and unable to populate the grid. Here is the cshtml code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EntryPointCRR.Models.GuarantorInfo>()
        .Name("kgGuarantor")
        .Columns(c =>
        {
            //  c.Bound(p => p.Id);
            c.Bound(p => p.Rank);
            c.Bound(p => p.GuarantorNameModel.Name);
            c.Bound(p => p.GuarantorNameModel.CisNumber);
            c.Bound(p => p.Type);
            c.Bound(p => p.GuaranteeShare);
            c.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit"" href=""\#""><span class=""fa fa-pencil""></span></a><a class=""k-button-icontext k-grid-delete"" href=""\#""><span class=""fa fa-trash-o""></span></a>");
        })
             .ToolBar(toolBar =>
             {
                 toolBar.Create().Text("Add Guarantor");
             })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                        .Create(create => create.Action("AddGuarantors", "Guarantor"))
                                            .Read(read => read.Action("GetGuarantorSummary", "Guarantor", new { packageId = 1, packageProductId = 1 }))

            )
        )
```

and here is the my controller code

```
public ActionResult GetGuarantorSummary(string packageId, string packageProductId)
        {
            GuarantorModel objGuarantorModel = new GuarantorModel();
            try
            {
                //Guarantors objGuarantors = new Guarantors(packageId, packageProductId);
               // objGuarantorModel = objGuarantors.GetGuarantorsSummary();
                objGuarantorModel = GetGuarantorsStubbedData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Write(ex, "General", 1, 1, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error);
            }
            return View("Guarantor", objGuarantorModel);
        }

  private GuarantorModel GetGuarantorsStubbedData()
        {
            GuarantorModel objGuarantorModel = new GuarantorModel();
            objGuarantorModel.GuarantorDetails.Add(new GuarantorInfo
            {
                Id = 1,
                Rank = "1",
                Type = "Full",
                GuaranteeShare = "30%",
                GuarantorNameModel = new GuarantorNameModel
                {
                    Name = "Acme",
                    CisNumber = "12345"
                }
            });
            objGuarantorModel.GuarantorDetails.Add(new GuarantorInfo
            {
                Id = 2,
                Rank = "3",
                Type = "Full",
                GuaranteeShare = "40%",
                GuarantorNameModel = new GuarantorNameModel
                {
                    Name = "Acme Company",
                    CisNumber = "123456"
                }
            });

            return objGuarantorModel;
        }
```

I can see only the grid header not the data. 
Can you please hep me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your "GetGuarantorSummary" action result as per the below:

```
 public JsonResult GetGuarantorSummary([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string packageId, string packageProductId)
        {
           // GuarantorModel objGuarantorModel = new GuarantorModel();
            try
            {
                //Guarantors objGuarantors = new Guarantors(packageId, packageProductId);
                // objGuarantorModel = objGuarantors.GetGuarantorsSummary();
                //objGuarantorModel = GetGuarantorsStubbedData();
                List<EntryPointCRR.Models.GuarantorInfo> model = new List<EntryPointCRR.Models.GuarantorInfo>();
                //get your collection here:
                //TODO: My collection 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Write(ex, "General", 1, 1, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error);
            }
            return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
```

To do this change make sure you have the following using statements

```
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
```

Without these the DataSourceRequest Model and Extension methods will not work.

When returning your object back to the Grid make sure you are sending back a collection as that is what the grid is expecting and as you have indicated the grid is expecting the model type **EntryPointCRR.Models.GuarantorInfo** make sure this is the model type being sent back to the grid otherwise you will get a type mismatch.

Hopefully this provides you with a way of getting you started any issues let me know.